# use javascript to terminate firefox browser

Tags: javascript, firefox

i programmatically start a browser, running firefox, from a windows application. i want to add a button and connect the button, using javascript, to an onClick event to terminate the browser. I did try window.Close(), but that does not work.  the order of events is as follows:  app -> start firefox -> runs my own js script -> on the script i have an exit button -> depress exit button -> firefox terminates and control back to the app.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible. A script can only close a window that it opened. If the window wasn't opened by Javascript, it can't be closed by Javascript. It's a security feature.

Comment: Of course, you can't do that from a regular web site. Imagine the possibilities if any webmaster could decide to close all your browser tabs. You already have a native Windows app and I think that's the path to explore.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(element).click(function(){ window.close(); });
```

Note: you cannot close any window that you didn't open with window.open . Directly invoking window.close() will ask user with a dialogue box.